# Data not matching when imported from spss into r and spss into sas

Tags: r, sas, spss

I've been trying to import a spss (.sav) file into r and sas and match the data. Date variable is in huge numbers, so am converting it in R. I'.m getting the differences in date and time variables. One of the record where it shows start date in r is missing in sas. All the time stamps are 12.00.00 in r while 00.00.00 in sas. Can anyone please help me out where I am getting it wrong?

This is the code I used in R:

```
library("memisc")
data<-as.data.set(spss.system.file('aa.sav'))
library("chron")
data$formdate<-as.chron(ISOdate(1582, 10, 14) + data$formdate)
data$randdate<-as.chron(ISOdate(1582, 10, 14) + data$randdate)
data$med1start<-as.chron(ISOdate(1582, 10, 14) + data$med1start)
data$med1end<-as.chron(ISOdate(1582, 10, 14) + data$med1end)
data
```

and this is the code I used in SAS

```
proc import datafile="C:\ofc\aa.sav" out=mydata dbms = sav replace;
run;
```

To take a look of how data is both on R and SAS, follow this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNMQ2.jpg)
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which timestamp do you feel is correct - 12:00 or 00:00?  You likely need to show some examples - what does it show up as in SPSS, what is the underlying number (typically number of seconds since [some date])?

Comment: I'm not sure as I do not have spss. But I assume 00.00 time stamp is correct. The underlying number looks like 13558320000

Comment: Please edit it into the question in a readable manner (not behind a link).  Just a couple of examples is sufficient.

Comment: Regarding the missing value in SAS, are there any warnings in the SAS log that might indicate "invalid" data?

Comment: No the log is clean, it says data set was successfully created. No warnings or errors.

Comment: It is occurring for the variable med1start if you see the image I attached. There is a * in the raw dataset when it is not converted above. is that causing it?

Comment: `*` seems like an invalid date value to me...

Answer (score 1):

The datetimes in SAS are correct. The SPSS numbers represent the number of seconds since midnight, October 14, 1582. The reason R is adding 12 hours to the values is that the default value of the optional `hour` argument to the [ISOdate function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ISOdatetime.html) is `12`:

> ISOdate(year, month, day, hour = 12, min = 0, sec = 0, tz = "GMT")

If you use `ISOdate(1582, 10, 14, 0)` instead, you should get the right answer.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Can you clarify about why sas is missing that if you're aware of that issue?

Comment: I think it's more curious why R has that as default, personally.  My guess is that it is related to the Julian/Gregorian difference (Julian dates had a zero point of noon, not midnight), but who knows.  Perhaps it's just choosing to impute to the mean (12:00 is half of a day) rather than the origin (0:00, as SAS does) when a date is converted to datetime.